# Infinite Loop when it's supposed to end because it has a clear condition that should be met

Tags: python

So the objetive is that the list names sorted_resistances appends its first 12 items to the blocks_A[0] and then skip 12 items and pass the next 12 to the blocks_A[1] and so on until the length of blocks_A[28] equals 12. The problem is that its the while loop never ends when it should because blocks_A[28] should have 12 elements.(Its the while len(blocks_A[28]) < 12 loop)

```
from math import *

blocks_B = []
y = 0
while y < 29:
    y = y + 1
    block_y = []
    blocks_B.append(block_y)

blocks_A = []
y = 0
while y < 29:
    y = y + 1
    block_y = []
    blocks_A.append(block_y)

with open("file.txt") as file_in:

    list_of_resistances = []
    for line in file_in:
        list_of_resistances.append(int(line))
        sorted_resistances = sorted(list_of_resistances)

    while len(blocks_A[28]) < 12:
        z = 0
        w = 11
        x = 0
        for y in sorted_resistances[z:w]:
            blocks_A[x].append(y)
            blocks_A[x].sort()
        if len(blocks_A[x]) == 12:
            x = x + 1
            z = z + 24
            w = w + 24


print(blocks_A)
print(blocks_B)
```

Comment: You're appending to `block_A[x]`, which is one element. That wouldn't be such a big problem if you weren't resetting x every loop iteration.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal x should be a number between 0 and 28 because i want it to append 12 numbers to each index of the list (for information each index is kinda like a sublist) so x should vary right? I used something like this in a program before and it worked but now it doesnt

Comment: That is true, but the third assignment in your while loop, `x = 0`, makes it so the only index in `block_A` which gets accessed is 0.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal but doesnt the if statement that comes next to that change the x in the loop or is there any problema with that statement

Comment: The `x, z, w` declarations should come _before_ the loop, otherwise each time you do the next iteration the values get reset to their initial state.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal worked perfectly that and changing w to 12

Comment: I'm curious how you didn't notice the wrong placements in this loop but you _did_ do it correctly on the two loops prior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing from `0:11` stops at 10, so it only gives you 11 elements, so you never step forward the `x`.

You are also resetting the `x` to zero every iteration of the `while` loop. Put the `x = 0` along with the `w` and `z` assignements before the while loop.

Comment: Even if I change w to 12 it doesnt seem to end the loop.

Comment: Yeah, I missed another bug. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is with the way it increments the z and w variables within the loop. The values of z and w should increase by 12 after each iteration, but they're increasing by 24 instead. This means that the loop will never end as z and w will never reach the end of the sorted_resistances list.